# Select all files from directory that contain file with given name

Tags: scope, phpstorm

I would like to create scope that contain all files from directory that contain files with given names.

My example pseudo-pattern:

```
file:*/box-wideo.tpl/./ *
```

I mean all catalogues (and it's content) that contain file box-wideo.tpl

Comment: Could you **please** clarify this a bit (with screenshot): what files you have and what files you would like to have selected.

Comment: So .. you want to see only `box-wideo.tpl` files (located anywhere in your project) .. or ALL files that are located next to `box-wideo.tpl` file? If first -- easy, if second -- I do not think it's possible. That's why I've asked to illustrate with screenshot -- its **MUCH clearer** that way.

Comment: Yes, I want the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scopes do not support conditional inclusion (e.g. "include folder IF it has specific file in it").**

Scopes work on file/folder names directly, i.e. "include files that match this pattern but exclude these that match another pattern).

Therefore it's not possible to do what you are asking for.

References to the manual:

- http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/scope-language-syntax-reference.html
- http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/scopes.html